# How to build a non-MFC C++ project with static linking to VC run-time libraries?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, windows-7, msvcrt

I know that for an MFC project built with Visual Studio, one can go to the project properties and then `Configuration Properties` -> `General` -> `use of MFC` and change it to `Use MFC in a static library`:

[image]

This works if the resulting build has to run in earlier versions of Windows without the need to install MFC or VC run-time DLLs. The resulting build will use DLLs that are already present in every installation of Windows since Windows 7 and up. (Possibly even down to Windows XP.)

Now if I create a non-MFC project, say a test C++ console application, the setting to use MFC is configured as "Use standard Windows Libraries":

[image]

But if I run the resulting binary file, say on a fresh install of Windows 7, I get this error:

[image]

So having dug around the settings, I couldn't find any way to compile it with static linking to all those newer versions of VC RT libraries. Is it there and I just don't see it?

PS. Having dug in further, I found out that I can change the "Platform Toolset" to `Visual Studio 2017 - Windows XP (v141_xp)`, assuming that it will make it backwards compatible with Windows XP and up:

[image]

But then if I compile it, I'm getting these errors:

```
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.1a\include\objbase.h(239): error C2760: syntax error: unexpected token 'identifier', expected 'type specifier'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.1a\include\dbghelp.h(1540): warning C4091: 'typedef ': ignored on left of '' when no variable is declared
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.1a\include\dbghelp.h(3056): warning C4091: 'typedef ': ignored on left of '' when no variable is declared
```

In this part of `ObjBase.h` file which has nothing to do with my test C++ console project that I just created from a Visual Studio template:

[image]

So my question is -- can I build a non-MFC C++ project that can run on older versions of Windows without the need to install VC Runtime or any other additional libraries?

Answer (score 1):

Go to C / C++ -> Code Generation. Set `Runtime library` to `Multi-threaded /MT` instead of `Multi-threaded Dll /MD`

Comment: Nope. That didn't do it.